# How to make histogram using tikzpicture of lot of data?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, histogram

This problem is making me crazy, I have been sitting all day trying everything I can figure out without any useful results. I have a csv file like this:

```
3001, 3001, 15001, 7206, 7217, 7617, 15001, 7215, 7536, 7206, 7557, 7212, 7158, 7833, 8394, 15001, 8103, 10736, 15001...
```

I want to plot how often the different numbers occur and make a histogram out of it. There is about 1 million numbers in total. In case that is too difficult for tikzpicture to handle, I also made a csv file like this:

```
data,count
1361,8
1377,8
1385,2
1389,2
2001,20
...
```

Where the data has already been counted. This file only has 540 lines. The problem is that many numbers are very close to each other, and therefore the bars in a bar plot end up on top of each other. I have therefore made another csv file with bins that look like this:

```
data,count
1000,20
2000,20
3000,5195
...
```

But I cannot figure out how to plot that either... I am running out of ideas. How can I plot this data????

This is my best attempt so far:
The full data:

```
data,count
1000,20
2000,20
3000,5195
4000,0
5000,0
6000,501392
7000,1481
8000,495
9000,163
10000,683
15000,114
20000,0
30000,0
40000,0
50000,2240
60000,0
70000,0
80000,0
90000,0
100000,213734
110000,0
120000,0
130000,2923
200000,37
```

The code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
                    ybar,
                    bar width=1pt,
                    ymin=0,
                    x=2cm,
                    scaled x ticks=false,
                    x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
                    xtick=data,
                    xticklabels={1 000 - 1 999,2 000 - 2 999,3 000 - 3 999,6 000 - 6 999,7 000 - 7 999,8 000 - 8 999,9 000 - 9 999,10 000 - 14 999,15 000 - 19 999,50 000 - 59 999,100 000 - 109 999,130 000 - 199 999,200 000 - 304 969},
                    xlabel=Sampling Rate (Hz),
                    ylabel=Count]
              \addplot table[x=data,y=count,col sep=comma] {dataset_stats/all_files_length_samples_binned2.csv};
        \end{loglogaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

The result:
[image: the result]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try something which you could show here? It would be easier to help you then.

Comment: Welcome. Show us how you produce the diagrams that don't look good for you ("bar plot end up on top of each other"). The second input (table with value and count) is most likely better to visualize with PGFPlots or plain TikZ since the work of counting them wouldn't need to be done by TeX/TikZ/PGFPlots.

Comment: Okay, I will add some code within 1 or 2 minutes

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I have added the code, data and plot now

Comment: Can we also see the data for the 540 line option? Wouldn't `ybar interval` make more sense for this kind of data? I'd start by using `$\leq 1999$`, `$\leq 2999$`, … labels.

Comment: Side note: maybe TikZ isn't the best tool for this.

Comment: @anis what else can I use? I want my paper to look consistent, and therefore I dont want to use matplotlib graphs or similar :/

Comment: Like @anis said, looks like this is a better job for R, both in terms of data processing and plotting. There are different routes to tikz/latex later, e.g.: a) including an image from R, b) do your tikz drawings with better preprocessed data, c) use one of the R-related packages from ctan.

Comment: I think the `addplot`-option `ycomb` might be a good alternative to a bar plot. This way, you can get a plot similar to the stem plot using MATLAB (with or without the addition of a mark like `mark=o`). This might help with the 540 lines version, but I only tested it with the first 5 entries. Might a solution using this be interesting to you? As @Qrrbrbirlbel requested, the full 540 lines might be helpful for that.

Comment: @J.Doe Clarity > consistency. Also results should be displayed in their unique style as it makes reading easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest two options, one for the grouped data and one for the list of counts for discrete values.

First, for the grouped data, I think `ybar interval` might be the best visualization. That way, the interval width is already given by the width of the bars in combination with relevant tick labels. I still ran into a little overlay/close labels problem for 100 and 130 kHz, which I could only resolve by leaving out one of the ticks. Also, with a `loglogaxis` zeros can't be handled well, so I had to work around it. I assume, that there might be a better way to handle the ticks, but this is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{adjusted_data.csv}
data,count
1000,20
2000,20
3000,5195
4000,1e-1
5000,1e-1
6000,501392
7000,1481
8000,495
9000,163
10000,683
15000,114
20000,1e-1
30000,1e-1
40000,1e-1
50000,2240
60000,1e-1
70000,1e-1
80000,1e-1
90000,1e-1
100000,213734
110000,1e-1
120000,1e-1
130000,2923
200000,37
304696,1e-1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
            ybar interval,
        ymin=1,
        x=2cm,
        xtick=data,
        x tick label as interval=false,
        % xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,200},
        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,{},6,{},8,{},10,15,20,{},{},50,{},{},{},{},100,{},{},{},200},
        xlabel=Sampling Rate (kHz),
        ylabel=Count,
        fill=blue]
                \addplot table[x=data,y=count,col sep=comma] {adjusted_data.csv};%
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: ybar interval for grouped data]

Note that I had to trick a little by overwriting the zeros in the data with a small number and cut off everything below 1 via `ymin`. I also added a final point with 304969 for the last interval.

Alternatively, when counting the discrete values, a plot similar to stem in MATLAB might be a good alternative to a bar plot without the overlay problem. This could be achieved via `ycomb` in the `addplot` option like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{loglogaxis}[%
    xmin=1300,
    xmax=305000,
    ymin=1,
    ymax=1e6,
    xlabel=Sampling Rate (Hz),
    ylabel=Count
]
\addplot[ycomb, color=blue, forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
    1361    8\\
    1377    8\\
    1385    2\\
    1389    2\\
    2001    20\\
};
\end{loglogaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Here, I'm not sure how good/readable the plot is with the full data. There still might be some problems distinguishing lines of close values, as seen below for the first few data points.

[image: stem-like plot]